# Gallery in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, gallery, horizontalscrollview

I am showing all the images in the gallery in `HorizontalScrollView`. As we all know that `HorizontalScrollView` will show all the images, even the images that are not visible. This results in an `OutOfMemory` exception.

How can we show all the images of a `Gallery` in `HorizontalScrollView` while avoiding `OutOfMemory` error?

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView with horizontal Layout manager ....

Comment: LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: This will show images in one row. I am showing them in two rows.

Comment: @NilayDani Try to edit your answer and post the code you just commented in it. The answer should contain all information necessary to help the OP and the comments are just to ask / notice parts of the answer.